# Get route parameters in Azure API Management Inboud policy section

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a URL with template parameters.

```
https://test.azure-api.net/HelperFunction/{siteId}/lots/InventoryItem/{itemId}
```

```
https://test.azure-api.net/HelperFunction/122/lots/InventoryItem/12
```

I wanted to read the template/path parameters in inbound policy section.

I am trying as below. But it will only fetch the query string parameters. I wanted to get the path parameters.

```
 <inbound>
        <set-body>@{
                JObject transBody = new JObject();
                transBody.Add("Arguments", 
                new JObject
                {
                    {"method", context.Request.Method},
                    {"parameters", context.Request.Url.QueryString},
                });

                //Add all json properties as arg
                transBody.Add("UriPath", context.Request.Url.Path);
                return transBody.ToString();
            }</set-body>
        <base />
 </inbound>
```

My requirement would be to read route parameters as

```
"siteId" : 122,
"itemId" : 12
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

`context.Request.MatchedParameters["siteId"]` and `context.Request.MatchedParameters["itemId"]`

Rest of context variable can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ContextVariables

Comment: I need the whole collection. I don't know what parameters will be in request. I need to fetch dynamically all the request path parameters.